# import multiple CSV into HDF5 using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, hdf5

i trying to import multiple CSV files in a specific path into dateset HDF5 file using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import glob
yourpath = '/root/Desktop/mal/ex1'
all_files = glob.glob(yourpath + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None, header=0)
li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

hf = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=frame)
hf.close()
```

But i have an error:

line 15, in  frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 281, in concat sort=sort, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 329, in init raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate") ValueError: No objects to concatenate –

Answer (score 0):

try to concat the csv file this way:

```
PATH = r"/...." # your Path
extension = 'csv'
os.chdir(PATH)
csv_list = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
print(csv_list)

# creates new df
df = pd.DataFrame()

for csv in csv_list:
    temp = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df = pd.concat([df, temp], ignore_index=True)
    
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)

# .... here comes the rest of your code
```

Comment: its working put still have issue when i creat dataset  hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=df)        the error is "TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent"